# How do I detect when the user drags a lifted subject from ImageAnalysisInteraction?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, visionkit

I am using [ImageAnalysisInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/imageanalysisinteraction) to allow the user to press and hold part of image to lift it and drag it somewhere else. I got the drop part working, but how do I detect when they started dragging?

The delegate and `interaction` function below help me find out when the user pressed and held, but not when they started dragging the image. This is a new [iOS 17 API](https://www.wwdcnotes.com/notes/wwdc23/10176/).

```
class ImageAnalysisViewController: UIViewController, ImageAnalysisInteractionDelegate {
    func interaction(_ interaction: ImageAnalysisInteraction, shouldBeginAt point: CGPoint, for interactionType: ImageAnalysisInteraction.InteractionTypes) -> Bool {
        print("lifted subject")
        return true
    }

    [...]
    
    let interaction = ImageAnalysisInteraction()
    var imageView: UIImageView?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        guard let imageView = imageView else { return }
        
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.addInteraction(interaction)
        interaction.delegate = self
    }
}
```