# How to detect when the user starts dragging a text selection?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

iOS 11 introduced the ability to drag and drop text and images. So for example I can select some text, *then* press and hold it again and drag it into a text field or another application.

In Swift code, how can I detect when the user starts dragging some selection? The finger moves, so I tried a drag gesture handler but that does not work, the dragging of the selection is on some other "layer" that does not trigger it.

Comment: Have you looked at `UITextDragDelegate` and `UITextDropDelegate`? Apple docs: [Drag and drop customization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/drag_and_drop_customization)

Comment: @DonMag do you know if there is an equivalent for images?

Comment: The docs state: *The UITextField and UITextView classes provide built-in support for dragging and dropping text and images.* ... are you looking for something else?

Comment: @DonMag Hmm, that does answer this question, but what I am actually trying to do is solve this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76751649/ and I was hoping for a solution that isn't specific to `UITextField` and `UITextView`. If you answer with the docs, I will mark that as answer and close this question though.

Comment: I haven't look at the `iOS 17` new APIs yet... but have you watched this video? [Lift subjects from images in your app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10176/) ... very possibly you'll find something there.

Comment: I have, yeah, sadly they do not cover this, instead using a UIHoverGestureRecognizer with an Apple Pen to get around this